# include()d div does not take width and height from parent

Tags: php, html, css

I have got a page `index.php` with a div:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="statusBar"><!-- some content here !--></div>
        <div class="screen"><?php include("content.php"); ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The stylesheet from this page, `indexStyle.css`:

```
.statusBar{
    position:fixed;
    height:5%;
}

.screen{
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    min-height:95%;
}
```

`content.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="contentStyle.css">
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- some content here !-->
</div>
```

`contentStyle.css`:

```
.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

But when I run this code, the `wrapper` is only the height that is minimum necessary for the content to display, not the at least the full screen.

It seems like the `wrapper` does not look at its parent, in this case `screen`. Is this because I `include("content.php")`? How can I fix this?

For your information: the stylesheets do work, I have tested this. Also, `include("content.php")` works fine, since I do see the content inside `wrapper`.
And: the `screen` does cover the full height of the window, from `statusBar` to bottom of the page.

**EDIT:** After messing around a lot with `min-height` and `height` I decided I had enough and decided to do it with JavaScript. I take the height from the `screen` and put it in the `wrapper`. It works, not very elegant though.

Comment: `link` element belongs into `head`, you are producing invalid HTML by including it within `body`.

Comment: the problem is not with the include, the problem is how you want to work with min-height
(if you copy the content of content.php into index.php and move all css also into index.php after then it will still not work)

Comment: That aside, height in percent requires the parent element to have an explicit height set – yours has only a min-height, and that doesn’t work.

Comment: @CBroe It is not invalid HTML, since the stylesheet does work and produces other wanted results. Only the height does not work. I use `min-height` for `.screen`, because I want it to fill up the complete screen, but if there is more content, it has to continue as well. If that is the problem, how can I change `min-height` in `.screen` so that it still fills up the whole screen but also expands when necessary?

Comment: Since .screen is position:absolute, why can't you just give it bottom:0 to force it to cover the screen?

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount: _“It is not invalid because it works”_ is a dumb statement. That’s the same as saying robbing that bank was legal because they didn’t catch me (yet).

Comment: _“I use min-height for .screen, because I want it to fill up the complete screen, but if there is more content, it has to continue as well”_ – and that is simply impossible here, because you want to have the child element, that would hold this “more content”, to have a height in percentage as well. And that would mean you have two values that depend on each other in their calculation, and that is simply unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CBroe about where the link is referenced, but if you change min-height to just height (but keep it on the .wrapper class to extend), that should take care of it:  ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3an7pdaw/2/))

```
.statusBar{
  position:fixed;
  height:5%;
}

.screen{
  position:absolute;
  top:5%;
  height:95%;
}
.wrapper{
  min-height:100%;
}
```

In regards to the stylesheet link, why not just reference the included css like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexStyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contentStyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="statusBar"><!-- some content here !--></div>
    <div class="screen"><?php include("content.php"); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: To keep div adjustable to content, keep min-height on ONLY the .wrapper class

Comment: As replied to CBroe I really need the `min-height` property on `.screen` since the div needs to expand when there is more content. With `height` it will not expand and the background color will not continue behind further content if it reaches the end of the screen and thus the end of `height:95%`. So yes, this does take care of it, but not in the way I want it to. Nonetheless, thanks for your answer. In the end I have 'fixed' it with some JS, not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: What if you use min-height on the .wrapper class, and keep height on the .screen class?  This seems to work when I edit the content in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3an7pdaw/2/